# Why doesn't assignment work on this DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a copy df with different values based on the previous one. I have used this technique before and it worked just fine, however it doesn't work here.

Does anyone know if I am missing something?

Code:

```
df2 = df1.copy()

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    flowers_num = int(row["flowers_num"])

    if flowers_num >= 100:
        flowers_num = 10
    elif flowers_num >= 10:
        flowers_num = 8
    else:
        flowers_num = 6

    row["flowers_num"] = flowers_num
```

Unique values on df2 before loop:

```
[  0.   1.  10.  15.   6.   2.   4.   3.  44.   8.   9.   7.  22.   5.
  11.  19.  12.  13.  21.  20.  14.  23.  16.  18.  24.  17.  35.  32.
  25.  30.  28.  57.  45.  27.  42.  38.  43.  37.  34.  26.  29.  41.
  52.  31.  39.  46.  51. 131.  36.  61.  53.  33.  48.  40.  58.  49.
  76.  50. 119.  55.  91.  59. 106.  56.  65.  54.  47.  63.  64.  67.
  75. 102.  74.  70.  60.]
```

Unique values on df2 after loop (should be just 6, 8 or 10):

```
[  0.   1.  10.  15.   6.   2.   4.   3.  44.   8.   9.   7.  22.   5.
  11.  19.  12.  13.  21.  20.  14.  23.  16.  18.  24.  17.  35.  32.
  25.  30.  28.  57.  45.  27.  42.  38.  43.  37.  34.  26.  29.  41.
  52.  31.  39.  46.  51. 131.  36.  61.  53.  33.  48.  40.  58.  49.
  76.  50. 119.  55.  91.  59. 106.  56.  65.  54.  47.  63.  64.  67.
  75. 102.  74.  70.  60.]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `row["flowers_num"] = flowers_num` won't modify your dataframe. Anyway, you shouldn't be using `iterrows` to begin with

Comment: Iterrows creates a copy most of the time. That’s why shouldn’t set a value on row. And what the others mentioned.

Comment: Have you not read the Pandas docs? In any case, don't use `.iterrows()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much faster if you use apply on the column rather than iterrows.

Create a function to change the values

```
def change_num(x):
    if x>=100:
        return 10
    elif x>=10:
        return 8
    else:
        return 6
```

Dummy DataFrame:

```
df_ex = pd.DataFrame({'flowers_num': np.random.randint(1,1000,20)})
```

Using apply:

```
df_ex["flowers_num"]=df_ex["flowers_num"].apply(change_num)
```

Comment: `Series.apply`, which is what you use, **is** still a loop over the rows. Your function takes a single `int` and you loop over all values in the column, one row at a time.

Comment: Ohh thanks, I thought the series.apply does vectorized apply but learnt it only happens with numpy ufuncs.

Answer (score 6):

Your coded worked from me, however, the "pandas" way to do this is to use `pd.cut`:

```
pd.cut(df1['flowers_num'], [0,10,100,np.inf], labels=[6,8,10])
```